# What's a good free to use tool to compare data across databases?

Tags: open-source, database

I'm searching for a tool that allows me to explicity declare a couple of databases,  each one with a query and compare the results periodically.
Something like [DiffKit](http://www.diffkit.org/userguide.html) seems to follow this concept, but it is not been developed anymore.

**EDIT:** I want to able to compare data from different DBMS's (say MySQL and Oracle).
I want to compare the table content. Compared tables can have different table schemas, so the tool must provide a way to match and compare those tables columns.

Comment: across instances of the same DBMS on different hosts (production and development, say), or  among different products (compare a Sybase RDBMs with a MS-SQL, say). Compare the schema or the table content (assuming we're talking about RDBMSs here)?

Comment: @knb i edited the question with more details

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this tool exists. I would dump all the required data to CSV files and compare them.

I've googled "csv diff" and found this tool https://github.com/aswinkarthik/csvdiff among the others.

If the tables have a different structure I think it's easier to write the custom solution using client libraries and some language that you know.

Answer (score 1):

I think [SQL Data Compare from RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) might be what you want.

It's a commercial product, not free, but I think it does what you want.

I've evaluated it in the past for my job and it worked just as advertised.  I ended up not using it though since it was decided we didn't really need it.